# Sign in with Firebase e-mail verification link

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I am doing e-mail verification using `Firebase`. I have configured all the things and sent the verification link.

The problem is that when I tap on the verification link, it opens my app and I get the link in the `AppDelegate` method. But for some reason, I am not able to sign in with this link. Here is my code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
        if let DeepLinkUrl = dynamiclink?.url?.absoluteString {
            if DeepLinkUrl.contains("verifyEmail") {
                if Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: DeepLinkUrl) {
                    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: SBUserSetting.getVerificationEmail() ?? "", link: DeepLinkUrl ) { (user, error) in
                        print("user", user)
                        print("error", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return handled
}
```

`Auth.auth().isSignIn()` is always returns `false`

Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using email verification or sign-in with email link? They are different from each other. That may be why `Auth.auth().isSignIn()` is false.

Comment: I am using email verification. if Auth.auth().isSignIn() is not required, then what should be the code instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use passwordless login (this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth#verify_link_and_sign_in), then you can't use conversion from url to DynamicLink. You need only pass raw url to your method like this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let webpageUrl = userActivity.webpageURL {
        if Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: webpageUrl.absoluteString) {

            // Saved email locally before, where you send verification, so you don't need to ask the user for it again
            // if they open the link on the same device.
            if let emailToVerify = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Email") {
                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailToVerify, link: webpageUrl.absoluteString) { (user, error) in
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        // User is logged in
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

But if you want to use method *sendEmailVerification* you need this:

```
func sendEmailVerification() {
    let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
    actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://yourdomain.com")
    // The sign-in operation has to always be completed in the app.
    actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
    actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleId) // Budle identifier of your application

    Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification(with: actionCodeSettings, completion: { error in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // inform user about sending verification email
        }
    })
}
```

Then you can handle arrived email with DynamicLink class like this:

```
func handleDynamicLink(_ url: URL?) -> Bool {
    guard let url = url else { return false }
    // Here don't know, which method will work, so I handle both for sure :-)

    if !DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(url, completion: { dynamicLink, error in
        if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
            if let oobCode = dynamicLink.url?.getQueryString(parameter: "oobCode") {
                Auth.auth().applyActionCode(oobCode) { error in
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        // Email was successfully verified
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    }) {
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            if let oobCode = dynamicLink.url?.getQueryString(parameter: "oobCode") {
                Auth.auth().applyActionCode(oobCode) { error in
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        // Email was successfully verified
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Here is my own url extension method *getQueryString* for separating component from url.

```
extension URL {

    func getQueryString(parameter: String) -> String? {
        if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: self.absoluteString) {
            return urlComponents.queryItems?.filter({ item in item.name == parameter }).first?.value
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler. The deep link will contain a query parameter `oobCode`. You will need to parse that and then use `applyActionCode` to complete verification. The docs are focused on the web implementation but should be portable to iOS.